# Relation 1:n in Drag and Drop is not saved, when I open the project file again

Tags: qgis, drag-and-drop

My new created relation 1:n in the "Drag and Drop Layout" is not saved when I open the project file again. When I look at the layout the field is empty, but I can delete it and put it there new and it works until I reopen the project, even if I save the project.
With older created relation in my project I haven't got this problem.[image: layout]